# About the floatation of bodies on a surface

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, surface-tension, buoyancy

A body which is partially floating in water is in equilibrium due to the balancing of the buoyant force and the weight of the body. Now what will happen to a body floating on the surface of the liquid without displacing the volume of the liquid? It is obvious that surface tension won’t be enough. So how will the buoyant force come into play.

[image]

Comment: [3.3 Walking on water – the story of surface tension](https://gtgwithscience.com/blog-series/science-blogs/the-word-around-us/3-3-walking-on-water-the-story-of-surface-tension/) and the [paper cited in the article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269040621_Enhanced_wavelength-dependent_surface_tension_of_liquid-vapour_interfaces)

Comment: Why is that obvious to you that the tension force isn't enough? If it floats on the surface, it can be solely due to the tension force. If you think of something else, then you have to define what you mean by "floating on the surface". And never forget the golden rule which has no exceptions: solution of every single physical problem must be started with a computational schematic (a.k.a "drawing"). So, go ahead and draw the computational schematic for your problem. If after that you can't solve your problem, go ahead and formulate a precise question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, for an object to "float" (i.e., not sink) in a liquid, the density of the object must be less than or equal to the density of the liquid. On the other hand, one can take a metal paper clip, which clearly has a density greater than water, and if very carefully placed  on the surface of a cup of water it will "float" (not sink).

Just to be clear, the paper clip does displace a small volume of water and experience slight upward buoyant force. It's just that the buoyant force alone is insufficient to prevent the paper clip from sinking. It is the surface tension force, which makes the surface of water behave like a stretched membrane, that is primarily responsible. That force is not based on the weight of the volume of water displaced but on the relationship between the length of the object in contact with the surface of fluid, its mass, orientation, and properties of the fluid. An MIT professor calculates the maximum mass a paper clip of certain dimensions can have for it to float in water in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlC48WRPl14

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The case of a body in a liquid is a subset of the more general problem of a body in equilibrium under surface stresses and its own weight.

For example: a car under the stress of the contact of the (slightly deformed) tires with the ground that balances its  weight.

The difference for a body in a liquid is that the upward normal force can be calculated by integration of the pressure over all the submerged surface. And the pressure is a function of the depth.

For example: in the picture, the Normal force is the product of the bottom area by the pressure at that depth. The body is in equilibrium if it equals its weight.